# Connot connect my Index.js with Mongodb, how can i connect them to create an API with node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose

[nodemon] restarting due to changes...

[nodemon] starting `node index.js`

Server started: 5500

Connection error :MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I was doing exacty the same that the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjR52rCqlQU, I do every thing well till the 16', then i never have mongodb connected. my error was : Connection error :MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017

Answer (score 0):

- If `c:\data\db` folder doesn't exist then create it by yourself.
- Go to mongo folder in you machine for example `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin\` Open your cosole and type `mongod.exe --dbpath c:\data\db`
- Now it should works fine ;-)
- *Source from official [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) Good Luck ;-)*

Comment: I've done it but still the same probleme, i will continue to found the solution, thanks for your help and time anyway

Comment: @JulienLoubere If you attach a code to your question, it will be easier to solve ;-)

Comment: I was doing exacty the same that the following video: youtube.com/watch?v=hjR52rCqlQU, I do every thing well till the 16', then i never have mongodb connected. my error was : Connection error :MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 –